# Granting user privilege to create/drop database of specific name

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL user named mydb_user who has been granted ownership of mydb_dev.  mydb_user already has the privilege to drop the database, but I want him to be able to create the database again after deleting it.  If possible, I'd like him to only be able to create a database with the same name (mydb_dev) again, but if necessary, I will settle for letting him create a database with any name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to grant the user role the `CREATEDB` privilege.
The ability to drop the database is automatically granted to the DB owner, however you must have the `CREATEDB` privilege to create new databases -- Note that this allows the user to create a database with *any* name...

Comment: Right, but is there any way to only allow the user to create a db of a particular name?